# PhantomJSDriver (GhostDriver) can't get localStorage values using javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

Using PhantomJsDriver (GhostDriver) for testing my web application.
Trying to access the local storage values using calls like:

```
 (String) js.executeScript(String.format("return localStorage.getItem('%s');", key));
```

In webDriver initialisation I'm setting the capability:

```
 DesiredCapabilities dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities()
 dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
 dCaps.setCapability("webStorageEnabled", true)
 return new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps)
```

Receiving WebDriverException while trying to execution the JS above, from which it looks like the `webStorageEnabled` have been never set to true:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"SECURITY_ERR:
>   DOM Exception 18","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   image/png","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"98","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:20884"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"args\":[],\"script\":\"return
>   localStorage.getItem('cartId_136d7735-13d7-8178-8abf-010beb62f8cf');\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5f67ce30-310a-11e4-83c7-6d52cfce6b64/execute"}}
>   Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time:
>   '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
>
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=false,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false,
>   driverVersion=1.1.0, locationContextEnabled=false, version=1.9.7,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=false,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, **webStorageEnabled=false**,
>   nativeEvents=true, proxy={proxyType=direct},
>   applicationCacheEnabled=false, driverName=ghostdriver,
>   takesScreenshot=false}]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

What could be the reason for the issues I experiencing? Should it be possible to set webStorageEnabled for PhantomJSDriver? If no, how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I have managed to solve this issue.

In general, it's possible to access localStorage using using JavaScript. The issue described here happened because of something else.
Here is the flow I had:

1) Initialize WebDriver
2) Access localStorage
3) Doing `driver.get(url)`

The problem is, `driver.get(url)` must happen before accessing localStorage. That solved the issue.

Here is my LocalStorage driver implementation (in Scala), if you need one: [LocalStorageDriver](https://gist.github.com/stas-slu/1d355033683729454652)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's still not implemented:

- https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/6c918e230cc98a7bce75e652c020c55cc3e0dd23/src/session.js#L65
- https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/25

Comment: It's a bit different. You can still access localStorage using JavaScript. The issue i had happened because of something else - i tried to access localStorage after WebDriver have been initialised but, **before** i did driver.get(url).